# Calling a function that decodes in base64 in bash

Tags: linux, bash, file, base64

```
#!/bin/bash

#if there are no args supplied exit with 1
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Unfortunately you have not passed any parameter"
        exit 1
fi

#loop over each argument
for arg in "$@"
do
    if [ -f arg ]; then
                echo "$arg is a file."

                #iterates over the files stated in arguments and reads them    $
                cat $arg | while read line;
                do
                    #should access only first line of the file
                        if [ head -n 1 "$arg" ]; then
                                process line
                                echo "Script has ran successfully!"
                                exit 0
                        #should access only last line of the file
                        elif [ tail -n 1 "$arg" ]; then
                                process line
                                echo "Script has ran successfully!"
                                exit 0
                        #if it accesses any other line of the file
                        else
                                echo "We only process the first and the last line of the file."
                        fi
                done
        else
                exit 2
        fi
done

#function to process the passed string and decode it in base64
process()   {
        string_to_decode = "$1"
        echo "$string_to_decode = " | base64 --decode
}
```

Basically what I want this script to do is to loop over the arguments passed to the script and then if it's a file then call the function that decodes in base64 but just on the first and the last line of the chosen file. Unfortunately when I run it even with calling a right file it does nothing. I think it might be encountering problems with the `if [ head -n 1 "$arg" ]; then` part of the code. Any ideas?

EDIT: So I understood that I am actually just extracting first line over and over again without really comparing it to anything. So I tried changing the if conditional of the code to this:

```
                    first_line = $(head -n 1 "$arg")
                    last_line = $(tail -n 1 "$arg")
                    if [ first_line == line ]; then
                            process line
                            echo "Script has ran successfully!"
                            exit 0
                    #should access only last line of the file
                    elif [ last_line == line ]; then
                            process line
                            echo "Script has ran successfully!"
                            exit 0
```

My goal is to iterate through files for example one is looking like this:

```
MTAxLmdvdi51awo=
MTBkb3duaW5nc3RyZWV0Lmdvdi51awo=
MXZhbGUuZ292LnVrCg==
```

And to decode the first and the last line of each file.

Comment: Have a look at the syntax highlighting. There is a `"` missing after `echo "We only process the first and the last li$`. Also, you have to define `process()` *before* using it. For these kind of mistakes please try https://www.shellcheck.net/. -- What do you try do do with `if [ head -n 1 "$arg" ]`? Either way it won't work as it is now, but I'm not sure how to fix it because I don't know what you plan to do with it.

Comment: @Socowi probably got lost while copy pasting it's there, going to edit the question

Comment: I want to check whether it's the first line of the given file and if it is I want to decode it @Socowi

Comment: That's exactly where I struggle to understand you: What is "*`it`*"? For every line in the file `$arg`, you extract the first line of the file `$arg`, but never compare it to anything.

Comment: Maybe you could add an example (input arguments, files, and file contents) and the expected output. That would probably be easier than describing your goal in words.

Comment: Going to edit the question. @Socowi

Comment: Thanks for all your effort, but you still didn't get your goal across. Since you seem to be unable to provide a complete example, let's do the guessing game: **Is your goal...** *for a given file, extract the first line that is equal to either the first line or the last line (of course the first line is always equal to the first line, so we skip that one; same for the last line). If such a line is found, base64-decode it.* **? And...** *this task should be done for each file in a list of files*.

Comment: My goal is to extract BOTH first and last line of the given file *which is passed as a parameter when calling the script* and base64-decode those 2 lines and echo the decoded message.

Comment: You have to remove all the whitespace surrounding the _assignment_ `=` operator.

Comment: Ok, that last comment really cleared things up for me. I would have never guessed that. Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: Sorry for throwing obstacles at your feet. I thought in my head that it's pretty clear. Well i guess not. Thanks for the help tho! @Socowi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decode the first and last line of each file given to your script, use this:

```
#! /bin/bash  
for file in "$@"; do
  [ -f "$file" ] || exit 2
  head -n1 "$file" | base64 --decode
  tail -n2 "$file" | base64 --decode
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea, as the others already said the true goal of the script isn't really clear. That said, i imagine every variation of what you may have wanted to do would be covered by something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

process() {
    encoded="$1";
    decoded="$( echo "${encoded}" | base64 --decode )";
    echo "    Value ${encoded} was decoded into ${decoded}";
}

(( $# )) || {
    echo "Unfortunately you have not passed any parameter";
    exit 1;
};

while (( $# )) ; do
    arg="$1"; shift;
    
    
    if [[ -f "${arg}" ]] ; then
        echo "${arg} is a file.";
    else
        exit 2;
    fi;
    
    
    content_of_first_line="$( head -n 1 "${arg}" )";
    echo "Content of first line: ${content_of_first_line}";
    process "${content_of_first_line}";
    
    
    content_of_last_line="$( tail -n 1 "${arg}" )";
    echo "Content of last line: ${content_of_last_line}";
    process "${content_of_last_line}";
    
    
    line=""; linenumber=0;
    while IFS="" read -r line; do
        (( linenumber++ ));
        echo "Iterating over all lines. Line ${linenumber}: ${line}";
        process "${line}";
    done < "${arg}";
    
done;
```

some additions you may find useful:

If the script is invoked with multiple filenames, lets say 4 different filenames, and the second file does not exist (but the others do),
do you really want the script to: process the first file, then notice that the second file doesnt exist, and exit at that point ? without processing the (potentially valid) third and fourth file ?
replacing the line:

```
exit 2;
```

with

```
continue;
```

would make it skip any invalid filenames, and still process valid ones that come after.

Also, within your **process** function, directly after the line:

```
decoded="$( echo "${encoded}" | base64 --decode )";
```

you could check if the decoding was successful before echoing whatever the resulting garbage may be if the line wasnt valid base64.

```
if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo "    Value ${encoded} was decoded into ${decoded}";
else
    echo "    Garbage.";
fi;
```

--

To answer your followup question about the IFS/read-construct, it is a mixture of a few components:

```
read -r line
```

reads a single line from the input (-r tells it not to do any funky backslash escaping magic).

```
while ... ; do ... done ;
```

This while loop surrounds the read statement, so that we keep repeating the process of reading one line, until we run out.

```
< "${arg}";
```

This feeds the content of filename $arg into the entire block of code as input (so this becomes the source that the **read** statement reads from)

```
IFS=""
```

This tells the read statement to use an empty value instead of the real build-in IFS value (the internal field separator). Its generally a good idea to do this for every read statement, unless you have a usecase that requires splitting the line into multiple fields.

If instead of

```
IFS="" read -r line
```

you were to use

```
IFS=":" read -r username _ uid gid _ homedir shell
```

and read from /etc/passwd which has lines such as:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/usr/share/httpd:/sbin/nologin
```

then that IFS value would allow it to load those values into the right variables (in other words, it would split on ":")

The default value for IFS is inherited from your shell, and it usually contains the space and the TAB character and maybe some other stuff. When you only read into one single variable ($line, in your case). IFS isn't applied but when you ever change a read statement and add another variable, word splitting starts taking effect and the lack of a local IFS= value will make the exact same script behave very different in different situations. As such it tends to be a good habbit to control it at all times.

The same goes for quoting your variables like "$arg" or "${arg}" , instead of $arg . It doesn't matter when ARG="hello"; but once the value starts containing spaces suddenly all sorts of things can act different; suprises are never a good thing.

Comment: I edited the answer with the explanation for that (see above)

Comment: Oh thanks very much! That explanation is absolutely spot on. @Raxi